# How to pass keys and values in ModelForm ModelChoiceField in django

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-queryset, modelform

I have three tables user, doctor, and patient.
User table contains Username , password, status , etc.
User table is auth table of Django.

doctor table contains id, user_id(foreign key),and other information.

patient table contain doctor_assignid(foreign key), name ,etc.

so, trying to get the username from user table and id form doctor table. And pass those
data in ModelForm ModelChoiceField.

```
 class PatientForm(forms.ModelForm):

assigned_doctor=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=None,empty_label="Name of the Doctors",to_field_name='username')
class Meta:
    model= patient
    fields=['patient_first_name','patient_last_name','address','mobile','age','symptoms']
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.request = kwargs.pop("request")
    super(PatientForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.request:
       
        users = self.request.user.id
        adminId = hospitalAdmin.objects.all().filter(user_id=users).values('pk')
        doctors=doctor.objects.filter(assigned_hospitalAdmin=adminId[0]['pk'])
        userTableDoctor = User.objects.filter(id__in=[i.user_id for i in doctors],status=True)
        userTableDoctor = userTableDoctor.values('username','doctor__id')
        assigned_doctor= self.fields['assigned_doctor']
        assigned_doctor.queryset = userTableDoctor
```

but, I'm getting dictionary like querset like this
[image]

[image]

which is not an acceptable parament to pass. So, I want to display the username and If the user selects the username the backend receives the doctor id.
So, is there any way to pass as an object or any other way to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Delete this line:

```py
userTableDoctor = userTableDoctor.values('username','doctor__id')
```